# CSVへの書き込みができません。教えて下さい

Tags: python, python3, csv

`i`と`j`のすべての総当たりをしたいのですが、以下の構文で走りません。
Python 3.6です。どう修正すべきでしょうか。

```
l = [1,2,3,4,5]
g = [6,7,8,9,10]
p = [1,2,3]
q = [4,5,6]

import csv
f = open('data99.csv', 'ab')
csvWriter = csv.writer(f)

listData = []
for i in range(len(l)):
   for j in range(len(p)):
      a = l[i] * p[j] + g[i] * q[j]
      listData.append(a)
         writer.writerow(listData)
f.close()
```

Comment: 質問文を書く際に書き間違えたのかもしれませんが、`writer.writerow(listData)` は `csvWriter.writerow(listData)` ですよね。それと、この行のインデントはこれで良いのでしょうか？

Answer (score 2):

csvファイルは、コンマ区切りのデータ列を含むテキストファイルです。
それなのに、質問のコードでは

```
f = open('data99.csv', 'ab')
```

と出力先のファイルをバイナリモード(b)で開いています。そのため、思っているようなデータ(テキスト)が得られていないのではないでしょうか。また、ファイルを追記モード(a)にする必要があるのかというのも疑問です。

コードの上記の行を以下のように変更してみてください。

```
f = open('data99.csv', 'w')
```